# jQuery Mobile - dynamically replacing script tag within html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I can see the value when I print it out within console log, however I don't see the value being populated in the html page within list.html. So I am guessing that I need to make sure that the element has been loaded prior to it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

html:

```
<script type="text/html" id="searchPickPlaceTemplate">
<div class="searchPickWhere_box">
    <ul data-inset="true">                             
        <li><a data-transition="slide" id="searchPickWhere" href="list.html">{{whereSearch}}</a></li>                             
     </ul>
 </div>
```

​

Script:

```
 $('#restWhere').bind('touchstart mousedown', function (e) {                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: WebServiceURL + "GetSuburbsWithPlacesAndCity",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'cityId':'" + cityId + "', 'categoryId': '" + categoryId + "'}",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#searchPickPlace").html("");
                    $.each(result.d, function () {
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            console.log('SubrubName asdfsd ' + this.name);
                            var test = $("#searchPickPlaceTemplate").text();
                            test = test.replace("{{whereSearch}}", this.name);
                            $("#searchPickPlace").append(searchPickRestaurnt);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi. Please check your code, so we can help you: in the HTML there is an opening script tag without the corresponding closing one; and it doesn't have a `src` attribute; and the type wouldn't be `text/javascript`?. Also, Where is `#restWhere`? (I suppose it is a button/div/something near `searchPickWhere_box`).

Comment: There is a couple of tips about your problem. First: the `$(document).ready()` don't (or shouldn't) work there: By the time your ajax call has been made, `ready` event should already has been triggered. Second: Your `console.log(...)` works, so your ajax call works too, but you should add a console.log(test) so you can verify that your are getting the value that you want to replace (I think you aren't).

Comment: @Roimer - sorry I'll try my best to describe. The #restWhere is a button. I'll have to get the info for you soon I need to get more details when I am next in work!

Comment: @Twisty - I may have inadvertently not marked them as accepted answers.

Comment: Hi @Roimer please see my jsfiddle link below. Thanks.

Comment: When I output test I get this : <div class="searchPickWhere_box">
                         <ul data-inset="true">                             
                             <li><a data-transition="slide" id="searchPickWhere" href="search-list.html">Remuera</a></li>                             
                          </ul>
                     </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

1. Remove $(document).ready(function () { from each block, it is not going to work with it and you don't need it.
2. Replace this line: $("#searchPickPlace").append(searchPickRestaurnt); with this $(".searchPickPlace").append(test); You were appending the wrong thing to the wrong element.

Here's an dumb down example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/tJBGw/

So it should look something like this:

```
$('#restWhere').bind('touchstart mousedown', function (e) {                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: WebServiceURL + "GetSuburbsWithPlacesAndCity",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'cityId':'" + cityId + "', 'categoryId': '" + categoryId + "'}",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#searchPickPlace").html("");
                $.each(result.d, function () {
                    console.log('SubrubName asdfsd ' + this.name);
                    var test = $("#searchPickPlaceTemplate").text();
                    test = test.replace("{{whereSearch}}", this.name);
                    $(".searchPickPlace").append(test);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey @Gajotres, all good. I'll get myself with a proper jsfiddle so it's easier to get help. And thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think it's kinda working.. first time around when I click I get this : http://www.flickr.com/photos/79621732@N03/8277843243/ and second time around http://www.flickr.com/photos/79621732@N03/8277843085/. Not sure why it be getting cleared out.. even though I am simply replacing the value.

Comment: I have managed to get this working i think.. had to use pageshow and pageshow again.. http://jsfiddle.net/antaeusa/XD8A7/4/

Answer (score 0):

always try to place your JavaScript codes just before the html body tag. for example:

```
<body>
    your html code
    <script>
         // your js code
    </script>
</body>
```

or use the jQuery document ready function. you have to use it only once, NOT in every iterations.

Thank you